# calling Web service via ajax - proper response in my error callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to get some data from a web service via ajax using the below function,
but I get this response message:

```
{"readyState":4, "status":200, "statusText":"load"}
```

The WS is supposed to return an array of json and, if I look in my chrome dev tool
in network tab -> Response, I actually get the proper array of json.

Question:

1. Why am I getting the result in my errorFunction callback?

```
function callWebService(wsUrl, params, successFunction, errorFunction) {

    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', ' GET');
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
                "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        },
        type: "GET",
        url: wsUrl,
        data: params,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: successFunction,
        error: errorFunction
    });
}
```

Here is my console.log when I use this error function `function(jqXHR, status, error)`

```
*Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.myweb.it/services/service.php?callback=jQu…y21109160579217132181_1405523828314&codice_istituto=150201&_=1405523828315". jquery.js:8691send jquery.js:8691jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:8152callWebService global.js:5(anonymous function) index.js:49jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:4409elemData.handle jquery.js:4095
an error occurred: index.js:52
parsererror index.js:53
Error {stack: (...), message: "jQuery21109160579217132181_1405523828314 was not called"}message: "jQuery21109160579217132181_1405523828314 was not called"stack: (...)get stack: function () { [native code] }set stack: function () { [native code] }__proto__: d index.js:54
readyState: 4 index.js:56
jqXHR.status: 200 index.js:57
jqXHR.statusText:load index.js:58
jqXHR.responseText: undefined*
```

Comment: That looks like the [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object to me.

Comment: i think although this is in error callback but your call got the response so `{"readyState":4, "status":200, "statusText":"load"}`.

Comment: @Blazemonger what do you mean by this? (I am new to ajax)

Comment: Not to be rude, but a web search for "ajax readyState status" would turn up several promising results.

Comment: @Blazemonger, right but I cannot easily find "statusText":"load"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing the `error` callback fired because there's something wrong with your AJAX request, and it's not returning successfully. Identifying *why* this happens is another matter.

The first argument jQuery passes to your `error` callback is the [jqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR):

```
error 
Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )
```

This is different from the `success` callback, which begins with the `data` returned:

```
success
Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
```

`jqXHR` is a superset of the [`xmlHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object JavaScript returns. Inside it, you're seeing `readyState` of 4, which simply means "done", and `status` of 200 means a successful request. So, at least you know you're probably pointing your request at the right URL.

You should be able to get other information from your `jqXHR` object which might help you identify the cause of the error. From the docs:

> For backward compatibility with XMLHttpRequest, a jqXHR object will
>   expose the following properties and methods:
>
> - `readyState`
> - `status`
> - `statusText`
> - `responseXML` and/or `responseText` when the    underlying request responded with xml and/or text, respectively
> - `setRequestHeader(name, value)` which departs from the standard by    replacing the old value with the new one rather than concatenating    the new value to the old one
> - `getAllResponseHeaders()`
> - `getResponseHeader()`
> - `statusCode()`
> - `abort()`

Comment: are you saying that I should pass jqXHR instead than xhr?

Comment: jQuery passes those arguments to your callback automatically; what you do with them inside the callback is up to you. Try something simple: `errorFunction(jqxhr,status,error){console.log('an error occurred:');console.log(status);console.log(error);}`

Comment: I am getting this: Error {stack: (...), message: "jQuery21109151822538115084_1405518981908 was not called"}message: "jQuery21109151822538115084_1405518981908 was not called"stack: (...), Do you know the meaning?

Answer (score 0):

That object you're seeing is an [XMLHTTPResponse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest); a representation of the actual AJAX request. You're getting it passed into your error handler because [that's the first argument of jQuery's `ajax` error callback](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Figuring out why it's calling the `error` callback and not the `success` callback is harder. That `statusText` suggests that your server returned the string 'load' - is that a possibility? Another common problem is if your data isn't actually valid JSON. JSON's quite a picky format; if you're producing it yourself, you might have invalid whitespace or the wrong kind of quotes (or completely missing quotes). Check your data with a tool like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and make sure it's valid, and make sure that your server is *only* returning JSON - nothing else in the response body.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but: are you sure you've got your callbacks the right way round when you call your `callWebService` function?

Comment: Your function is defined as `callWebService(wsUrl, params, successCallback, errorCallback)`. It seems like you're getting a successful response from the server - it's got a 200 status code and you're sending back valid JSON - so when you call `callWebService`, have you maybe swapped the two callbacks by accident? If you accidentally do `callWebService('/example', {foo: 'bar'}, errorCallback, successCallback)` then your code will call the `errorCallback` function on success.

Answer (score -1):

Just a work around
 1. remove dataType:'json'
 2. parse json in success function call
    data = $.parseJSON(data);

Comment: He says he's not getting to the success function.

Comment: if he removes dataType:'json' it will get into success
its not going to success because it is somehow not able to validate as proper json

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong -- the object he's getting isn't the desired JSON response, it's a jqXHR object that's passed to the error function. None of the data he was hoping for is inside of it.

Comment: Exactly, jqXHR  is passed to failure function. But as he is saying he is getting proper response from server. that means jquery ajax is not able to validate it as proper json.

if he removes the datatype restriction, for every response with status 200 it will go to success function.